# Uncaught Error: connect ETIMEDOUT (net.Socket)

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, npm, electron

I am trying to send text to my network printer via tcp connection.

```
   function print(buf2){
   var printer = new net.Socket();

   printer.connect(printer_port, printer_name, function() {
     console.log('Connected');
     printer.write(buf2);
     printer.end()
   });
   }
```

Everything works fine, but after some time my application throws me the error **Uncaught Error: connect ETIMEDOUT** and it doesn't connect with my printer.

To fix it, I open a browser and navigate to my printers address(192.168.1.111) and then my application connects again but after some time it stops connecting and throws the same error (**Uncaught Error: connect ETIMEDOUT**).

The applications is written with electron and i use the net npm

```
   var net = require('net');
```

In my application every 3 seconds i call a get request and then i call the print method

```
  function proxy() {
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.get('my_link', function(response) {
    var jsonItem = JSON.parse(response)
    if(jsonItem.items.length > 0) 
    {
      var text_to_print = jsonItem.items[0].text
      print(text_to_print,text_id);
    }
```

Any suggestions what could cause this error?

Comment: It's clearly timing out. Do you ever close the connection?

Comment: @christo8989 Yes i think,  with  **printer.end()**  the connection ends.

Comment: What if you null `printer` and give it a new `net.Socket` object?

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: @christo8989 OS: windows 10, i have this part of code in a function so everytime i call this function i create new printer **var printer = new net.Socket();**

Comment: Do you know if the job ever finishes?

Comment: @christo8989 I know it finishes because when i call the function second time it works fine , but if i remove **printer.end()** and call the function second time it throws me error

Comment: What is net npm? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @christo8989 sure [link](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html)

Comment: Do you set the timeout? I think the timeout is a global variable. Also, add logging to the end event.

Comment: I'm not sure you provided enough code above to figure out your problem. Maybe you could share a little more.

Comment: @christo8989 i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

This should help you to debug.

```
function print(printer_port, printer_name, buf2) {
    var printer = net.createConnection(printer_port, printer_name, function () {
        //'connect' listener
        console.log("Connected!");
        printer.end(buf2);
    });

    printer.setTimeout(60 * 1000); //1 minute

    printer.on("end", function () {
        console.log("Disconnected from server!");
    });

    printer.on("timeout", function () {
        console.log("Timeout!");
        printer.destroy();
    });
}
```

Comment: the "end" works fine , in the "timeout" i get the error **printer.destoy is not a function** i think it must be printer.end().

Comment: @IvaneGomarteli  that's a typo. Sorry. It should be destroy.